# If $f$ is a map from a topological space $Y$ to a metric space $X$, to prove that $f$ i

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, continuity

If $f$ is a map from a topological space $Y$ to a metric space $X$, to prove that $f$ is continuous at y, is it enough to show that for all $\epsilon >0$, there exists $V_{y}$ (neigbhourhood of $y$ in  $Y$) such that $t \in V_{y} \Rightarrow f(t) \in D(f(y),\epsilon)$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It suffices to prove this. In fact, this is pretty much from the definition of continuity of $f$ at $y$.

Let us examine this in a more general setting.

Let $f:Y\to X$ be a map between *topological* spaces and $y\in Y$ be arbitrary.

We say, by definition, that $f$ is continuous at $y$ if for all neighborhoods $U$ of $f(y)$ in $X$, there is a neighborhood $V$ of $y$ in $Y$ such that $f(V)\subseteq U$.

Now in particular if $X$ is a metric space, then given any arbitrary neighborhood $U$ of $f(y)$ in $X$, we can find $\epsilon>0$ small enough such that $D(f(y), \epsilon)$ is contained in $U$, where $D(f(y), \epsilon)$ is the ball of radius $\epsilon$ centered at $f(y)$.

So if we have a neighborhood $V$ of $y$ in $Y$ such that $t\in V$ implies $f(t)\in D(f(y),\epsilon)$, then we have $f(V)\subseteq D(f(y),\epsilon)$ (trivially).
Now since $D(f(y), \epsilon)\subseteq U$, we have $f(V)\subseteq U$, showing continuity of $f$ at $y$.

An important question here is what is the motivation behind the chosen definition of continuity at a point $y\in Y$ for a map $f:Y\to X$ between topological spaces $X$ and $Y$.

Our intuition tells that we want to call $f$ continuous at $y$ if $f$ takes points nearby $y$ to points nearby $f(y)$.
Now open sets formalize the notion of "nearness" and hence the definition chosen is a reasonable one.